# Removing div using arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a five questions , and every question is hiding in the box numbered 1-5, once the user choose a number from 1 - 5, the box selected will pop up with the question.. 
And i want to know how to remove the selected box if the user press the right key, and if left key it will do nothing but pop up a big X mark ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Question1(){
             document.getElementById('Question').innerHTML = 'Question#1';
            }
            function Question2(){
             document.getElementById('Question').innerHTML = 'Question#2';
            }
            function Question3(){
             document.getElementById('Question').innerHTML = 'Question#3';
            }
            function Question4(){
             document.getElementById('Question').innerHTML = 'Question#4';
            }
            function Question5(){
             document.getElementById('Question').innerHTML = 'Question#5';
            }

            function showArrowKey(e) {
            arrowKey = e.which||e.keyCode;
            switch(arrowKey) {
                case 37: //left key
                    //Do nothing just pop up Big X mark
                    break;
                case 39: //right key
                    // Remove the selected div, and pop up Check mark
                    break;
            }
        }

    </script>
<div class = "container">
        <div id = "CompleteImage">
            <div  class = "squareInside" id="trigger-overlay1" onclick='Question1()'>1</div>
            <div class = "squareInside" id="trigger-overlay2" onclick='Question2()'>2</div>
            <div class = "squareInside2" id="trigger-overlay3"onclick='Question3()'>3</div>
            <div class = "squareInside2" id="trigger-overlay4"onclick='Question4()'>4</div>
            <div class = "squareInside2" id="trigger-overlay5"onclick='Question5()'>5</div>

        </div>
    </div>   <!-- container --> 
    <div class="overlay overlay-door" >
        <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><p id='Question' ></p></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, to remove an element, in this case a div, use:

```
$('div').remove();
```

Then to show the check mark, have it as another element probably below the div with the CSS: `display:none;`
Then with the removal of the div, reveal it again with jQuery

```
$('checkMark').show();
```